# How to analyse a Likert-type scale with a very small sample size (n=15)?

Tags: likert, small-sample

**Data description:** I have data from questionnaire data on 15 participants (small sample). Parents rated the frequency that they rough and tumble with their child: (1) Never, (2) not very often, (3) once per month, (4) once or more per week, (5) every day.

**Initial analyses:** So far I have created several bar charts and am explaining them using percentages (e.g., 78% of the boys rough and tumble with one or other or both of their parents once or more per week this figure is only 60% for the girls).

#### Questions

- Should I use  medians  instead of  means?
- Is the sample size of 15 too small for meaningful results?
- Can I perform a meaningful Chi-square or other statistical test?

Comment: In broad terms, chi-square tests are possible, but the sample size of 15 is likely to bite in one or two ways (1) your expected frequencies may be small (2) you need strong effects to establish significant differences. Also, the chi-square tests take no account of the Likert scale. Those are reasons why many people would prefer Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon or ordinal logit here, although as said your sample size is small. In broad terms, if sample size is small for one test it is small for another and using a different test is not a solution. Using the best test for the data is always a good idea.

Comment: Incidentally, this really hasn't much to do with a Likert scale.

Answer (score 3):

With a sample size of 15, any difference that is statistically significant will have to be huge, but the results will be "meaningful".

However, as an analysis technique, I'd suggest ordinal logistic regression with the Likert scale as the dependent variable and one independent variable at a time.